# Python error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'type' and 'int'

Tags: python, typeerror

```py
def up_low(s):
    upper = int #If I change this to 0 it works fine
    lower = int #If I change this to 0 it works fine
    for i, l in enumerate(s):
        if l.isupper():
            upper += 1
        elif l.islower():
            lower += 1
    print(f"No. of Upper case characters : {upper}")
    print(f"No. of Lower case Characters : {lower}")

s = 'Hello Mr. Rogers, how are you this fine Tuesday?'
up_low(s)
```

Can someone please explain why can't I use int placeholder?

Comment: `int` is the integer type itself, not an instance of that type.

Comment: What's wrong with using the `0`?

Comment: use `upper: int = 0`

Comment: even if you were doing this in a language that requires type declarations, wouldn't you want `upper = int(0)`? otherwise you aren't specifying your initial value. but in python you don't do this, just say it's 0.

Comment: also `for i, l in enumerate(s)` would typically be just `for l in s` seeing as you aren't using i anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `int()` instead. `int` itself is a type and not an instance.

```
>>> int()
0
>>> type(int())  # int() returns an integer (with value 0) usable in calculations
int
>>> type(int)  # int returns a type, not usable in calculations
type
```

Comment: Oh okay, thank you! I am new to python so this is super helpful!

Comment: No worries :) glad I can help. It really depends on the programming language, but as mentioned by @Thierry Lathuille, it makes more sense to just use `0` in Python

Answer (score 2):

The message is clear, `int` is a type of object, not a number.

You could use `int()` though, which creates an integer with a value of 0 - but then, it's clearer and simpler to just use `0`.

Answer (score 1):

In Python you *don't* assign types to variables. Your lines

```
upper = int
lower = int
```

do not do what you think they're doing. They're assigned the *type* `int` not set to int. You've pointed it out correctly in your question, if you set it to `0` it works. That's because it's assigned an integer, with value `0`, which than can be incremented.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the tow lines --> upper = int(), -->lower = int()

```
def up_low(s):
    upper = int() #If I change this to 0 it works fine
    lower = int() #If I change this to 0 it works fine
    for i, l in enumerate(s):
        if l.isupper():
            upper += 1
        elif l.islower():
            lower += 1
    print(f"No. of Upper case characters : {upper}")
    print(f"No. of Lower case Characters : {lower}")

s = 'Hello Mr. Rogers, how are you this fine Tuesday?'
up_low(s)
```

> No. of Upper case characters : 4 No. of Lower case Characters : 33